# Javascript AJAX function return type undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, undefined

I am having an issue with some javascript logic where my function is being returned as undefined instead of the desired true/false I am looking for. I have tried everything imaginable including using callback functions and differed objects with JQuery. As soon as the AJAX call is finished, the function is undefined (right at the console.log statement). Can someone assist me?

```
function validateZip(countryCode, zip) {
    // US validation
    if (countryCode == 'US' && /^\d{5}([-\s]?\d{4})?$/.test(zip)) {
        getZipJson(zip).done(function(response){
            return isValid(response.results[0].address_components);
        });
        // international validation
    } else {
        return /^[A-Za-z0-9]{1,5}[-\s]?[A-Za-z0-9]{3,9}$/.test(zip);
    }
}

function getZipJson(zip) {
    var uri = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json';

    // need to add google api key to data
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: uri,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { address: zip }
    }).success(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}

function isValid(address_components) {
    var resultFound = false;

    $.each(address_components, function (i, component) {
        var types = component.types,
            country = component.long_name;

        $.each(types, function (j, type) {
            if (type == 'country' && country == 'United States') {
                resultFound = true;
                return false; // break out of .each loop
            }
        });

        if (resultFound) {
            return false; // break out of .each loop
        }
    });

    return resultFound;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Which version of Jquery are you using?

Comment: You are using the "GET" verb and have data on your request. You are supposed to use "POST" if you are sending data in the body of the request.

Comment: What happens when you move your return statement inside your success function? Doesn't look like you are returning anything.. Just logging the response to the console.

Comment: @Urielzen — They aren't sending data in the body of the request. The data option gets turned into a query string when you make a GET request.

Comment: @MikeC — Not a duplicate of that, the console.log statement the question is asking about is in the success callback.

Comment: @Duncan — Moving the return statement there would make this a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). While the question uses the word "return" it clearly means that the console.log statement isn't logging the expected data (since it talks about console.log printing undefined and there aren't any other uses of that function).

Comment: @Quentin My mistake. I saw `return isValid(response.results[0].address_components);` and jumped the gun.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: http://jsbin.com/migilo/1/edit?html,js,console

Comment: I tried his code on JsFiddle, It work when I remove "http:" from url
https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/4858/

Comment: The `.success()` method was a short-lived feature for `jQuery.ajax()`. You should either use the `success:` option or [`.done()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/).

Comment: @RogerRussel We are using jQuery JavaScript Library v1.11.1

Comment: @Quentin I'm sorry, I meant if I throw a breakpoint on the console.log statement, the validateZip function already is undefined before even finishing up the rest of the logic.

Comment: @maynevent — But you don't log the return value of `validateZip` in the code you supplied! Even then, it shouldn't be undefined, it should be a jQxhr object (although still not anything from the HTTP response because: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call )

Comment: Are your page Https?

Comment: @Quentin I can get the json data just fine. The issue I am having is that after retrieving the ajax'd json and filtering through the response json, the function is coming back as undefined. I need the function to return a true/false value. Try this, you'll notice there is no output from the code (all I did was removed the console.log statement and added validateZip('US', '12345'); at the end) http://jsbin.com/yekewikagu/edit?html,js,console . I am expecting a true/false to be returned

Comment: @RogerRussel Yeah, they are https

Comment: Finally I understand what is happening, the code you wrote never gonna work, let me explain...

Comment: When you call done function, it returns a promise that will be executed when the ajax is done, and the return of that promise is undefined.

Comment: See this, I put an console to show the return of function and the return of done promise, the undefined is showed firts, and when the ajax is done, the done funcion is called.
http://jsbin.com/guzunolisa/1/edit?js,console

Comment: @RogerRussel Thank you for that. Is there any way for this to return true/false instead of undefined?

Comment: Nope, but you can change your code to continuos after the result is done, I will put one exemple.

Comment: @Quentin Good point, for some reason I imagined there was a console.log statement in his isValid function, nothing was being returned so assumed the error was because he wasn't actually handling any data.

Comment: @maynevent, this is pretty much a duplicate of the post, Mike linked. It's exactly the same Problem, namely "How do I return whatever from an asynchronous call?". Take another look at my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37335561/5433027), I've extended it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can get the json data just fine. The issue I am having is that after retrieving the ajax'd json and filtering through the response json, the function is coming back as undefined. I need the function to return a true/false value.

That is simply not possible, because the ajax-rewuest answers a long time after the `validateZip` has been called and even returned. You have to go with one of the two possibilites of asynchronous programming: continuition aka callback, or promise. (**ES7** also introduces the keywords async and await, wich afaik. are just syntactic sugar for promises; like the class-keyword is just utilizes prototypal inheritance in a nicer way).

so, callback-style:

```
function validateZip(countryCode, zip, callback) {
    if (countryCode == 'US' && /^\d{5}([-\s]?\d{4})?$/.test(zip)) {
        // US validation
        getZipJson(zip).success(function(response){
            callback(isValid( response.results[0].address_components ));
        });
    } else {
        // international validation
        callback(/^[A-Za-z0-9]{1,5}[-\s]?[A-Za-z0-9]{3,9}$/.test(zip));
    }
}
```

and using Promises, in this case [jQuery.Deferred-objects](//api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

**this code needs jQuery 1.8 or higher, since it seems that the then-method behaves differently (weird/unexpected/false) below that**

https://jsfiddle.net/jge4439p/

```
//returns a promise
function validateZip(countryCode, zip) {
    if (countryCode == 'US' && /^\d{5}([-\s]?\d{4})?$/.test(zip)) {
        // US validation
        return getZipJson(zip).then(function(response){
            return isValid( response.results[0].address_components );
        });
    } else {
        // international validation
        return $.when(/^[A-Za-z0-9]{1,5}[-\s]?[A-Za-z0-9]{3,9}$/.test(zip));
    }
}

//also returns a promise ;)
function getZipJson(zip) {
    // need to add google api key to data
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { address: zip }
    });
}

//an ES5-version of isValid()
function isValid(address_components) {
    var isCountry = function(type){ return type === 'country' };
    return address_components.some(function(component){
        return (component.long_name === 'United States' || component.long_name === 'USA')
            && component.types.some(isCountry);
    });
}
```

and the usage:

```
var isValidPromise = validateZip("US", "12345");

isValidPromise.then(function(v){
    console.log("isValid", v);
});
```

or so:

```
validateZip("US", "12345").then(function(isValid){
    if(isValid){
        console.log("hooray");
    }else{
        console.log("ney");
    }
});
```

at a second look, the functions `getZipJson` and `isValid` are so specific, I don't know wether I would outsorce the code. Here the combined code, again as a promise:

```
function validateZip(countryCode, zip) {
    if (countryCode == 'US' && /^\d{5}([-\s]?\d{4})?$/.test(zip)) {
        // US validation
        var names = ['United States', 'USA'];           
        //using lambdas, because it's more compact and contains all necessary info
        var isValidComponent = comp => Boolean(comp && ~names.indexOf( comp.long_name ) && ~comp.types.indexOf( 'country' ));
        var isValid = result => isValidComponent( result.address_components );

        return $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { address: zip }
        }).then( response => response.results.some( isValid ) );
    } else {
        // international validation
        return $.when(/^[A-Za-z0-9]{1,5}[-\s]?[A-Za-z0-9]{3,9}$/.test(zip));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is because, one of the key values of Google JSON response is empty. And when your script loop thru that JSON and find one empty value it returns an `undefined` response (maybe one of `component.types` is empty or `component.long_name`), but this breaks all your request. I had the same problem using the Spotify API REST.

Try to console.log the full JSON object and look at the structure. If you see an empty value this may be the `undefined` one/s. When you parse it with an each loop, just try to replace that empty values with an empty string `''` or something similar.

In this cases I think is better to code with a simple plain JS function. It gives you more flexibility.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't believe that is the case. Here is the JSON data I am using to test with http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=12345

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to get "done" response was it was sync, but it was async.

When the code bellow execute:

```
getZipJson(zip).done(function(response){
                return isValid(response.results[0].address_components);
            });
```

The JavaScript not wait for the ajax request is done, but it deferred the Javascript anonymous function, that was given, to be called when the ajax request is done, and the done function that is called, return a promise that will be done.

It can be see into this fiddle: http://jsbin.com/wilawiziqa/1/edit?js,console

What you can do is it:

```
function validateZip(countryCode, zip) {
    // US validation
    if (countryCode == 'US' && /^\d{5}([-\s]?\d{4})?$/.test(zip)) {
        getZipJson(zip).done(function(response){
            var ok = isValid(response.results[0].address_components);
            continueValidation(ok);

        });
        // international validation
    } else {
        var ok = /^[A-Za-z0-9]{1,5}[-\s]?[A-Za-z0-9]{3,9}$/.test(zip);
        continueValidation(ok);
    }
}

function continueValidation(isZipOk){

  //Continue the validation process, but now, after ajax is finished.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your analysis, it is greatly appreciated :)